# Jquery mobile dialog close going to far back

Tags: jquery-mobile

I currently have a dialog that allows you to download a file, and another link (the one in question) to transfer the user to another page which links you to an external API.

When I pop up the dialog, I can click on `close` and the dialog closes properly. When I follow the external link the page loads correctly and everything like that.

However if I hit the back button, it keeps the `#ui-dialog` has in the URL and nothing is loaded into the page.

I have tried to set the `changehash` value to `false`, but when I do that and if I close the dialog, it takes me too far back in my browsers history.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    VaultManager.GetFolderConent(VaultManager.UserRootFolderGuid, "My Vault");
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
});

function PopDialog() {
    $.mobile.changePage( 'MobileFileOptions.htm', { reverse:false,  transition:'pop', role:'dialog' });
}
```

Instead of `PopDialog()`, I also tried this:

```html
<a href="MobileFileOptions.htm" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">
```

Here is `MobileFileOptions.htm`:

```html
<div data-role="page">//I have tried data-role="dialog" as well

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <h1 id="popupHeader">File</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="divFileName"></div>
        <div id="divFileSize"></div>
        <div id="divFileCreated"></div>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="javascript:VaultManager.DownloadFile();">Download</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="BoxManager.aspx" data-rel="external" id="boxLink">
                    Send to Box.NET
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Am I missing something somewhere?

I am fairly new with jQuery Mobile, so, I may have done some mistakes and I can't figure out to get much help from the docs.

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `document.ready` event handler(s), see the huge yellow warnings at the top of the Events page of the jQuery Mobile documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Ok I fixed that issue, I am adding stuff to legacy type code. But still not getting dialogs to work correctly